# Async call in akka stream flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want implement Diff transformation stream with such logic:

I have some `Source[JsValue]` and some database with id->JsValue data. I want to get Diff from `JsValue` in `Source` and db, then pull generated Diff further and store `JsValue` from source to db.

I think about Akka-persistence as store implementation, but I need only current state, so it can be any key-value db.

As I am new to akka-stream, I can't understand, what the best way is for implementing this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `JsValue` objects have an "id" field, you could write a querying `Flow` that would take in the original `JsValue` and produce a tuple of the original and database version:

```
def dbQuery(id : String) : JsValue = ???

val queryFlow : Flow[JsValue, (JsValue,JsValue), _] = 
  Flow[JsValue] map { originalJs =>
    originalJs -> dbQuery((originalJs \ "id").as[String])
  }
```

These tuples could be passed into a diffing `Flow`:

```
def diffJs(original : JsValue, dbVersion : JsValue) : JsValue = ???

val diffFlow : Flow[(JsValue, JsValue), JsValue, _] = 
  Flow[(JsValue, JsValue)] map diffJs.tupled
```

The final part you mentioned was a db that would persist the differences, [this can represented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400152/how-are-reactive-streams-used-in-slick-for-inserting-data) with a `Sink`:

```
val dbSink : Sink[JsValue, _] = ???
```

All of these components can then be combined to form the stream based on your source of values:

```
val jsSource : Source[JsValue, _] = ???

jsSource via queryFlow via diffFlow runWith dbSink
```

For an example of asynchronous db querying see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146418/difference-between-map-and-mapasync/35153765#35153765) demonstrating `mapAsync`.

Comment: thanks, I think about same way, but how about async `dbQuery: Future[JsValue]` in Flow and then in Sink? I can't use simple `map`.

Comment: @andrey.ladniy You are welcome.  I updated my answer with a link to a stack answer that is an exact demonstration of what you're looking for.  If there's anything un-accounted for there then I can update this answer...