# Send large List of Objects in Akka Http

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, akka-persistence

I have a large list of objects(possibly 1k-2k stored in db) on the server side that needs to be sent to multiple clients using Akka Http on client's request. The simple solution is I can retrieve it from DB on the server side, make Bytes of a list of Objects and then send bytes to a client and later convert that byte to object.

But the issue is it can impact memory performance on the client as well as a server as the list is very large.

So is there any best possible way to achieve this other than converting the whole list of an object into bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question involves several steps for both server side and client side.  Note: all of the code examples below are in scala rather than java for terseness.  On the server side you need to implement:

**1.  Streaming the Data from a DB**

There is [another stack question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999614/stream-records-from-database-using-akka-stream) that explains how to get rows out of a database using streaming methods.  The end result is that you have a source of rows:

```
type DataObject = ???

val source : Source[DataObject,_] = ??? // see linked answer
```

**2. Converting DataObject to Bytes**

This part can only be answered knowing the specifics of your data and it sounds like you already have this part implemented:

```
val converter : DataObject => ByteString
```

**3. Attaching to a REST Endpoint**

You can use [`akka-http`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/index.html?language=scala) to setup a REST endpoint that clients can query to get the data.  The `Source` of your `ByteString` values will be the Source feeding the stream entity for your `HttpResponse`

Setup a `Route` that responds to `GET` requests on a particular path:

```
val route : Route = 
  get {
    path("/queryDB") {
      complete(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, source.map(converter))))
    }
  }
```

And use the Route to launch your service:

```
Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
```

---

On the client side there are [similar mechanisms](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/connection-level.html) for reading data from an HttpResponse.

Comment: Thanks @Ramon J. Do I need to convert source to bytes and then send to client?

Comment: @rns You are welcome.  I don't fully understand your question.  The `HttpEntity` takes in a source *of* bytes (actually bytestrings but basically bytes).  Therefore, you don't convert the actual source to a bytestring.

Comment: @Thanks Ramon It worked by Slick, Streams and akka-http.|

 I have one more question, Is it possible to use streaming in existing Http application eg Spring or Camel and integrate Streams in it?

Comment: @rns I don't know the answer to that question as I have never used Spring or Camel.  I recommend a new stack question...