# Running out of memory when loading large amount of records from database

Tags: scala, akka, slick, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I am using slick in Akka Streams to load large number of records (~2M) from the database (postgresql) and write them to an S3 File. However, I'm noticing that my code below works for records around ~50k but fails for anything over around 100k mark.

```
  val allResults: Future[Seq[MyEntityImpl]] =
    MyRepository.getAllRecordss()

  val results: Future[MultipartUploadResult] = Source
    .fromFuture(allResults)
    .map(seek => seek.toList)
    .mapConcat(identity)
    .map(myEntity => myEntity.toPSV + "\n")
    .map(s => ByteString(s))
    .runWith(s3Sink)
```

Below is a sample of how `myEntity` looks like:

```
case class MyEntityImpl(partOne: MyPartOne, partTwo: MyPartTwo) {
  def toPSV: String = myPartOne.toPSV + myPartTwo.toPSV
}
case class MyPartOne(field1: String, field2: String) {
  def toPSV: String = {s"$field1|"+s"$field2"}
}
case class MyPartOne(field1: String, field2: String) {
  def toPSV: String = {s"$field1|"+s"$field2"}
}
```

I am looking for a way to do this in a more reactive way so that it doesn't run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Underlying Problem**

The problem is that you are pulling all of the records from the database into local memory before dispatching them to the `s3Sink`.

The first place that the data is being pulled into memory is likely in your `MyRepository.getAllRecords()` method.  Most, if not all, of the `Seq` implementations are in-memory based.  The second place where you're definitely utilizing local memory is in `seek.toList` because a `List` is storing all of the data in-memory.

**Solution**

Instead of returning a `Seq` from `getAllRecords` [you should be returning a slick-based akka `Source` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999614/stream-records-from-database-using-akka-stream/45015668#45015668).  This will ensure that your materialized stream will only need memory for the transient processing steps before going to s3.

If your method definition changed to:

```
def getAllRecords() : Source[MyEntityImpl, _]
```

Then the rest of the stream would operate in a reactive manner:

```
MyRepository
  .getAllRecords()
  .map(myEntity => myEntity.toPSV + "\n")
  .map(ByteString.apply)
  .runWith(s3Sink)
```